# Javascript, arrays show different length in different places

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have no idea what is wrong with my array. I want to check is element in array with x and y equal to pos.x and pos.y. If it's not I want to push it. 
My code:

```
checkSteps(pos) {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.path.steps.length; i++){
        if(this.path.steps[i].x == pos.x && this.path.steps[i].y == pos.y) return false;
    }
    this.path.steps.push({
        x: pos.x,
        y: pos.y,
    });
    console.log(this.path);
    return true;
}
```

I don't know why I can't do `this.path.steps.push(pos);` instead of `this.path.steps.push({x: pos.x,y: pos.y,});`

This `console.log()` give me:

[image: JSON]

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Can you please clarify what the intended output should be and why your current output is wrong.

Comment: Since your entire question surrounds `this.path.steps`, it is probably a good idea to include the code for it.

Comment: `I dont know why I cant do` We don't know why you can't either.  Does it give you an error?  What happens when you push `pos` onto the array?

Comment: As @AdamS said, your question is really unclear. I will note though that `this.path.steps.push(pos);` can be an issue because if you later reuse the same `pos` object, you'll just be adding the same object over and over and changing its coordinates, instead of recording new positions in the array (see: passing by value vs passing by reference). Don't know if that's what you meant.

Comment: I guess the function that calls `checkSteps` passes in a modified object into it multiple times, and the obkect reference stays the same. Therefore you would see the same data multiple times if you dont copy it before it gets changed.

Comment: I got this, it works fine, just weird console.log().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you log an array or object (or anything that isn't a primitive), the console shows a line (snippet) of the object/array at the moment the log happens, and caches a reference to that object/array.

When you unfold the object/array later, the console uses that previously cached reference to list the object/array content. The object/array may have been changed by the time you unfold it, that's why the console give you this message:

[image: console]

To inform you that the values listed have just been (re)evaluated.

**Demonstration:**

Open your console and type this:

```
var arr = [];
console.log(arr);

setTimeout(function() {
    arr.push(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    console.log("Unfold the above array now");
}, 5000);
```

Wait for the `"Unfold the above array now"` message and then unfold the previously logged empty array and see.